# Cannot run exe after building the jar

Tags: java, windows, netbeans, runtime-error, exe

I made a simple utility app. In it I had an exe file to be run. I got it to run by using:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(this.getClass().getResource("filename.exe").getPath());
```

I works perfectly when I run the program from the ide(Netbeans).

But when I try to run the exe using the above command after building(ie from the jar created on building) it does not work at all.

I also tried running this :

```
Desktop.getDesktop().open(new File("filename.exe"))
```

but no use again.

Please help

Comment: What error does it show? could be a classpath problem

Answer (score 1):

Tried with a usecase, found that getResource search for path "file:/path/to/thejar.jar!filename.exe", and is unable to use the exe inside the jar.

Tried modifying classpath, but failed.

---

Refered to spring's strategy, which reads config files in jar with an URL connection,
I think the solution can be :

- get an InputStream with getResourceAsStream
- copy the exe form inside the jar to a temp file with the ImputStream
- run the temp exe file located outside the jar.

---

This works (OK when compiled to jar, but NOK in IDE, 'cause "getResource" search at different place):

```
package me.mren.loadresource;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;

public class Runner {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            String filename = "/resources/filename.exe";
            System.out.println(Runner.class.getResource(filename));
            InputStream fi = Runner.class.getResourceAsStream(filename);
            File temp = File.createTempFile("temp_exe", "");
            System.out.println(temp.getPath());
            OutputStream fo = new FileOutputStream(temp);
            byte[] b = new byte[1024];
            int count = 0;
            while ((count = fi.read(b)) != -1) {
                fo.write(b, 0, count);
            }
            fi.close();
            fo.close();

            System.out.println(temp.canExecute());
            Runtime.getRuntime().exec(temp.getPath());

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Project's files structure:

```
C:\USERS\REN MIN\DEV ENV\JAVA\WORKSPACE\LOADRESOURCE
│  .classpath
│  .project
│  pom.xml
│
├─.settings
│      org.eclipse.jdt.core.prefs
│      org.eclipse.m2e.core.prefs
│
├─src
│  ├─main
│  │  ├─java
│  │  │  └─me
│  │  │      └─mren
│  │  │          └─loadresource
│  │  │                  Runner.java
│  │  │
│  │  └─resources
│  │          filename.exe
│  │
│  └─test
│      ├─java
│      └─resources
└─target
    │  loadresource-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
    │
    ├─classes
    │  │  filename.exe
    │  │
    │  └─me
    │      └─mren
    │          └─loadresource
    │                  Runner.class
    │
    ├─maven-archiver
    │      pom.properties
    │
    ├─surefire
    └─test-classes
```

the file structure inside the jar:

```
E:\TEST\RESULT
│  .classpath
│  .project
│  pom.xml
│
├─me
│  └─mren
│      └─loadresource
│              Runner.class
│
├─META-INF
│      MANIFEST.MF
│
└─resources
        filename.exe
```