# Exporting JAR with Ressources, Audio won't play

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, executable-jar

I made a small game that requires to play background music on it, I have images, a txt file and an audio file, they all work after exporting the JAR except for the audio file.

here is the code I used to import :

The Images :

```
(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/data/131868.jpg"))
```

The Text file :

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/data/dictionnaire.txt")));
```

The Audio file ( I included also the code to  play it that I found while searching) :

```
File f =new File(Main.class.getResource("/data/gmu.mp3").getFile());
final Player p=Manager.createRealizedPlayer(f.toURI().toURL());

        p.start();
        while(true){
            if(p.getMediaTime().getSeconds()==p.getDuration().getSeconds()){
                p.stop();
                p.setMediaTime(new Time(0));
                p.start();
            }
        }
```

Basically the `File` Object was : `File f = new File("/data/gmu.mp3")`   I just added modifications to make it look like the others ...

It did work in Eclipse, but not JAR.

Answer (score 1):

You'd better know that: File is just the name of the file, not the file itself. Like the house number, it tells you the house's location, but is doesn't represent the house.

So, you can use it like this:

`InputStream is = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/data/gmu.mp3");`

`File fi = new File(is);`

Tell me the result:)

Comment: How do I represent the file itself then ?

Comment: If I use it, I can't use `f.toURI().toURL()` since FileReader has no `toURI` method, and I cannot dast `f`

Comment: Give me the result: `System.out.println(f.toURI().toURL());`

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
 The method toURI() is undefined for the type FileReader

Comment: also, the constructor File(InputStream) is not defined

Answer (score 0):

#### Solution

Try placing the `gmu.mp3` inside the source before exporting the jar.

#### Why?

When you export a jar, it wraps all the fun code up that is inside the source folder. `File f = new File("/data/gmu.mp3")` simply points the program to that file names gmu.mp3 in the file system. If you place the `gmu.mp3` inside the source folder and update the `File` constructor to reflect the new location, the `mp3` should get wrapped up into the jar along with all the code.

Let me know how it goes -Scott

Comment: I put the audio file in the source folder `src` and updated the  `File` object to be `File("/data/gmu.mp3")` but I still get the same result, I don't know how this could work since I point my resource folder already ?

Comment: I want to make sure the jar you're compiling actually contains the resource you point at. A jar can be executed from anywhere. The file you point to is relative to the execution position, unless the file is placed inside the compiled jar.

Comment: The Audio File is in a `data` folder which is in the `src` folder, with all the other resources, when I export the java, The other ressources are all inside the JAR and they all work, except for the audio

Answer (score 0):

A java.io.File represents a jar-ed file as "ThePacked.jar!/path/inside/file.mp3", which makes problem when used as a File.

To read a jar-ed file's content, you can read from an InputStream given by getResourceAsStream(String filename).

or

To use the file as a real java.io.File, (what I did is to) read it from the InputStream and copy it to a location outside the jar (eg. to a temprary file).

Comment: I've another answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19299470/cannot-run-exe-after-building-the-jar/19300467#19300467 contains code for the "copy file solution".

Comment: so according to your link, the File I would use into `final Player p=Manager.createRealizedPlayer(f.toURI().toURL())` would be `fo` ??

Comment: If your **Manager** can accept an **InputStream**, use **InputStream** is the best way; otherwise, I suppose copy the mp3 to a temp-file and then **final Player p=Manager.createRealizedPlayer(tempFileUrl)**

Comment: Here is the code I added :

`File f =new File(Main.class.getResource("/tp/gmu.mp3").getFile());
  
  InputStream fi = Main.class.getResourceAsStream("/tp/gmu.mp3");
  File temp = File.createTempFile("temp", "");
        OutputStream fo = new FileOutputStream(temp);
        byte[] b = new byte[1024];
        int count = 0;
        while ((count = fi.read(b)) != -1) {
            fo.write(b, 0, count);
        }`  I get error at `Manager.createRealizedPlayer(fo.toURI().toURL());`  toTUI is undefined for outpoutstream

Comment: With the `File temp` created, `Manager.createRealizedPlayer(temp.toURI().toURL());` should work.

Comment: Exception in thread "main" `javax.media.NoPlayerException`: Cannot find a Player for :file:/C:/Users/Accent/AppData/Local/Temp/temp6192684826421114768
 at javax.media.Manager.createPlayerForContent(Manager.java:1412)
 at javax.media.Manager.createPlayer(Manager.java:417)
 at javax.media.Manager.createPlayer(Manager.java:332)
 at javax.media.Manager.createRealizedPlayer(Manager.java:527)
 at tp.Main.main(Main.java:46)

Comment: Make sure the file 'file:/C:/Users/Accent/AppData/Local/Temp/temp6192684826421114768' is correct (you may try to play it in a regular player). If the file is copied correctly, it is now a real java.io.File.

Comment: It is, shouldn't I ad `.mp3` as a suffix ?? so I'd have `File temp=File.createTempFile("temp", ".mp3");` ?? I did It and I had this error :

Comment: Error: Unable to realize com.sun.media.amovie.AMController@80669d
Exception in thread "main" `javax.media.CannotRealizeException`
 at javax.media.Manager.blockingCall(Manager.java:2005)
 at javax.media.Manager.createRealizedPlayer(Manager.java:528)
 at tp.Main.main(Main.java:44)
Error value: 80070020

Comment: Anyway, to add an `.mp3` extension is a good idea. If the issue comes from the `Manager`, I really don't know much about it.

Comment: Ok, maybe I should look for another way to play the music, thanx for your help !